# How to dynamically separate an array into multiple chunks?

Tags: javascript, arrays

The whole idea is to separate one array into multiple chunks.

Given I have an array named "mainlist":

```
const mainlist = [
  { label: '1' },
  { label: '2' },
  { label: '3' },
  { label: '4' },
  { label: '5' },
  { label: '6' },
  { label: '7' },
  { label: '8' },
  { label: '9' },
]
```

I have a second array as a reference to produce final chunks of arrays.

```
const fixedlist = [
  { label: 'f1', position: 3 },
  { label: 'f1', position: 5 },
]
```

I simply want to separate items from a `mainlist` based on each item's position from `fixedItems` list.

```
const output = {
  list1: [
    { label: '1' },
    { label: '2' },
  ],
  list2: [
    { label: '3' },
    { label: '4' },
  ],
  list3: [
    { label: '5' },
    { label: '6' },
    { label: '7' },
    { label: '8' },
    { label: '9' },
  ],
}
```

There are different scenarios to take into consideration, given there are only 2 loops:

1. for the first loop it should start slicing the array from the beginning till `position - 1`. in our case it's `2`. It should automatically create a new array with `fields.slice(0, 2)`
2. it also checks if if previous item exists, and if so, if there is a gap between previous item position and the current one. In first occurence there is not, but on the second one there is position `5 - position 3 = 2`, which means it should create a new list with 2 elements starting from the last one until the current one.
3. if current loop is the last one, and there are still items left after it's position, it should add them to new array list

Comment: Putting the code aside, it really isn't clear from your description, how the example output is deduced from the example input.

Comment: Sorry for missing details. I've updated my post, its a separation of array based on fixeditems list

Comment: Sorry it's still isn't clear at all, all I know is that you want to separate the main list but I have no idea based on what.

It's not just about our ability to help you, it's also about your own ability to solve the problem - you must define it well. What exactly does "position" mark? Where can I see the "3" and "4" in your example play in the result? What do "fixed 1" and "fixed 2" even mean? What is the "gap" you're talking about at the end?

Comment: Sorry for being bad in explanation, I tried one more time maybe it's clearer now. Thank you for your feedback

Answer (score 1):

After some reasoning I think you want to add those "fixed" markers into the list by their `position` which will split it to sublists. The trick is to first place the markers, then pour in all the rest. Lists of length 0 are ignored.

```js
const fields = [{ label: '1' }, { label: '2' }, { label: '3' }, { label: '4' }, { label: '5' }, { label: '6' }, { label: '7' }, { label: '8' }, { label: '9' }];
const fixedItems1 = [{ label: 'fixed 1', position: 3 }, { label: 'fixed 2', position: 4 }];
// const fixedItems2 = [{ label: 'fixed 1', position: 3 }, { label: 'fixed 2', position: 5 }];

const MARKER = "MARKER"

function combineListWithMarkers(list, markers) {
  const combinedList = [];

  var offset = 1
  for (let i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
    if (markers.some(item => item.position == i + offset)) {
      combinedList.push(MARKER)
      offset += 1
    } else {
      combinedList.push(list[i]);
    }
  }

  return combinedList;
}


// ChatGPT
function splitArray(arr, splitElement) {
  const result = [];
  let currentChunk = [];

  for (const item of arr) {
    if (item === splitElement) {
      result.push(currentChunk);
      currentChunk = [];
    } else {
      currentChunk.push(item);
    }
  }

  if (currentChunk.length > 0) {
    result.push(currentChunk);
  }

  return result;
}

const combinedList = combineListWithMarkers(fields, fixedItems1);
const splitted = splitArray(combinedList, MARKER)
const filtered = splitted.filter(item => item.length)
const objectified = filtered.reduce(function(agg, item, index) {
  agg["list" + (index + 1)] = item
  return agg
}, {})
console.log(objectified)
```